# require_once header.php isn't working

Tags: php

I am working on a website and Im trying to include/require header, global and footer files.
I have created all the needed files and saved them in the same folder. If I run header.php in chrome it is fully functional, but once included or required it is not working. I know it is simple but somehow I got stick at this point.

There are no error messages.

I am new to PHP and I have been checking syntax and usage rules but nothing so far, if someone could help get this running I would truly appreciate it. Any additional knowledge will be appreciated as well

Here is my code for require

```
<?php
require_once "global.php";
$page_title = "SELECT";
require_once "header.php";
?>
```

Comment: You say there are no error messages. Have you confirmed in your ini that errors are set to display?

Comment: use--> include('header.php');

Comment: Check the filename for case sensitiveness and try [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Comment: What directories are these files in? Once you require a file in a sub-folder, you are still running the script from the context of the parent folder, so if you go to includes/header.php, and the includes are in includes/test.php, it will work, but if you have index.php, it needs to include includes/header.php, and that file needs to include includes/test.php, unless you change the working directory.